# Trying to add image to a new window

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I'm opening a new window, a then trying to open an image in it. Instead of showing me the actual image it shows me an alt.

```
var popup = window.open('', popupName, 'width=600,height=600');
```

```
var image = popup.document.createElement('img');
                image.src = '../img/' + id + '.png';
                image.alt = 'Product Image';
                headerDiv.appendChild(image);
```

Also i cant see image in my files in the google developer console (source).

Tried everything, cant see a way for it to work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793173/how-to-put-a-picture-into-a-pop-up-window-in-javascript

Comment: You append `image` to `headerDiv`, why don't you append it to `popup`?

Comment: Because i want the headerDiv act like a wrapper

Comment: And where is that `headerDiv`? Is it in the popup? Could you please provide a working snippet so we could investigate?